# Bamboo Pen & Touch - Settings Program

Tags: 12.04, wacom

I wanted to use my Wacom Bamboo Pen & Touch on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.
The PC detects the tablet correct, but I don't really like the settings in
Ubuntu. I would like to set custom hotkeys for the pen and tablet buttons, like in
the original software from Wacom.

KDE seems to have a better support

http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Wacom_USB-Tabletts

Any ideas how to get this GUI for the settings?

Answer (score 0):

The first screenshot is the standard UI that comes with the wacom-tablet driver. I think it's saying you need kernel 3.2+ for the Pen & Touch (CTH-680) support. (For reference, the next LTS version, 14.04, has the correct drivers out of the box)

If you're having trouble with the wacom-tablet driver, a great resource for configuration of the tablet is [The thread here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1515562)

To your more specific question, you can install the second KDE UI with apt: `sudo apt-get install kde-config-tablet`
However, I think that is only for KDE desktops (see the [Ask Ubuntu question here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/462158/kde-config-tablet-on-ubuntu) or the [KDE Wikipedia Page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KDE).